# Is it safe to call abstract methods from constructor in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I am working on an android project. I want to make an abstract subclass of FrameLayout with an abstract method

```
@LayoutRes    
abstract fun getLayoutToInflate(): Int
```

In the constructor I want to inflate the layout returned by this method. But the IDE shows a warning about "Calling non-final function in constructor..." at this code

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
inflatedBanner = inflater.inflate(getLayoutToInflate(), this, true)
```

This app doesn't build yet. So wrote a simple kotlin code like this to test.

```
abstract class Base {
    val text: String
    constructor(text: String) {
        this.text = text
        println(text + getTextSuffix())
    }
    abstract fun getTextSuffix(): String
}

class Derived(text: String) : Base(text) {
    override fun getTextSuffix() = "_"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val d = Derived("stuff")
}
```

This code always prints "stuff_" which means that the overridden abstract method is available in constructor.
Can I rely on this behaviour in my app too? If not, what is the correct way to implement something like this in kotlin?

Comment: As long as the overriding methods don't access any state in the subclass, this is fine. If they do, they'll access uninitialized state.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this comment is probably good enough for an answer too :)

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin here is no different from Java or most other OOP languages.

As long as you make it clear in the method's contract that the overriding 
methods must not access any state in the subclass, you can safely call them from the base class's constructor. If a class breaks this rule, its method will be accessing uninitialized state.

Comment: "Kotlin here is no different from Java or any other OOP language." It is different from C++, for example. "From any JVM and CLR language" would be more correct.

Comment: Yep, I realized that while I was writing it... but C++ may be the only important exception and I find it a too detailed discussion. I changed to "most other OOP languages".